# Why does pinging work when you've shut down your Apache2 webserver?

Tags: apache2, ping

I'm new to Apache and Linux/Ubuntu and generally interested in understanding all the processes going on.

I just set up an Apache2 webserver on my Ubuntu 14.04 partition. I intend to run it as a local host only (mainly for testing out web design).

My question is about the operation I guess. I tried pinging my web server (ping -c (x) localhost) and it obviously came through loud and clear, but when I take it offline (etc/init.d/apache2 stop) I can still ping it and get a clear response back. Why is this? Does my computer become the default local host when the server is down?

Sorry, if this is a really stupid question. I'm very eager to learn the system!

Comment: Because ping is a different protocol then http See most any documentation on iptables ?

Comment: But if the server isn't running, why am I getting a response pinging?

Comment: The ping might be coming from your router, you have not posted enough information for us to tell you. Use a tool such as tracepath.

Comment: Also, `localhost` is just an alias for the PC itself. You can't access another PC using `localhost`, you'll have to use the IP address or hostname of the PC you want to reach for that.

Comment: ping localhost implies you are pinging a running machine, the request goes through the lo device.

Answer (score 0):

Ping requests are not handled by a web server - only http requests are. Ping requests are handled by the kernel, so you don't need a web server to answer a ping.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thanks for clarifying that for me. Still have a lot of learning to do!